# How can I find which MySQL query is causing errors in my NodeJS app?

Tags: mysql, node.js, hapi.js, knex.js

I have built an api on top of NodeJS and HapiJS.

The app loads a lot data at startup, and then holds it in memory. I have this app running on a server that has 16 gigs of RAM, so holding 4 gigs of RAM in memory should be possible.

However, every time the app starts up, this error appears 5 times in the log:

```
{ Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
    at Connection._handleConnectTimeout (/home/ec2-user/daemons/liar_lies/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:425:13)
    at Socket.g (events.js:291:16)
    at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at Socket._onTimeout (net.js:339:8)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:365:14)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:237:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:207:5)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/home/ec2-user/daemons/liar_lies/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:141:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/home/ec2-user/daemons/liar_lies/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:52:41)
    at Connection.connect (/home/ec2-user/daemons/liar_lies/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:136:18)
    at /home/ec2-user/daemons/liar_lies/node_modules/knex/lib/dialects/mysql/index.js:106:18
    at Promise._execute (/home/ec2-user/daemons/liar_lies/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/debuggability.js:300:9)
    at Promise._resolveFromExecutor (/home/ec2-user/daemons/liar_lies/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:481:18)
    at new Promise (/home/ec2-user/daemons/liar_lies/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:77:14)
    at Client_MySQL.acquireRawConnection (/home/ec2-user/daemons/liar_lies/node_modules/knex/lib/dialects/mysql/index.js:104:12)
    at Object.create (/home/ec2-user/daemons/liar_lies/node_modules/knex/lib/client.js:231:16)
    at Pool._createResource (/home/ec2-user/daemons/liar_lies/node_modules/generic-pool/lib/generic-pool.js:326:17)
    at Pool.dispense [as _dispense] (/home/ec2-user/daemons/liar_lies/node_modules/generic-pool/lib/generic-pool.js:314:12)
    at Pool.acquire (/home/ec2-user/daemons/liar_lies/node_modules/generic-pool/lib/generic-pool.js:392:8)
    at /home/ec2-user/daemons/liar_lies/node_modules/knex/lib/client.js:281:19
    at Promise._execute (/home/ec2-user/daemons/liar_lies/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/debuggability.js:300:9)
    at Promise._resolveFromExecutor (/home/ec2-user/daemons/liar_lies/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:481:18)
    at new Promise (/home/ec2-user/daemons/liar_lies/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:77:14)
  errorno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  fatal: true }
```

This is the only error, and it happens 5 times whenever the app starts.

And yet, the app does seem to get most of the data that I expect it to get, so whatever query throws this error, it must be fairly obscure.

How can I figure out which query is the one that throws this error?

The stacktrace does not seem to mention the line in my code that causes this. (I find this frustrating.)

These are the modules that I'm using:

```
"boom": "3.1.2",
"code": "2.1.0",
"fs": "0.0.2",
"glob": "6.0.4",
"glue": "3.1.0",
"good-console": "5.3.0",
"good-file": "5.1.2",
"hapi": "16.0.2",
"html-entities": "1.2.0",
"joi": "7.2.2",
"knex": "0.12.6",
"knex-logger": "0.1.0",
"multiline": "1.0.2",
"mysql": "2.12.0",
"path": "0.12.7",
"plugo": "0.3.1"
```

There are only 2 functions that I know of that call the database at startup time. This is one of them:

```
function build_maps_which_index_database_data(query, which_type_of_data_in_which_database_table) {

    DB.knex.raw(query).then(
        function(result) {
        var count_of_database_results = result[0].length;
        build_list_of_allowed_fields(result[0][0]);

        for(var how_many_records_processed_so_far = 0; how_many_records_processed_so_far < count_of_database_results; how_many_records_processed_so_far++) {
            var document = result[0][how_many_records_processed_so_far];
            var profile_id = document['profile_id'];
            document['which_type_of_data_in_which_database_table'] = which_type_of_data_in_which_database_table;
            document['item_id'] =  uuidV4(); 

            build_map_of_uuid_ids_to_documents(document);   

            Object.keys(document).forEach(function(name_of_field_in_database) {
                // avoiding name_of_field_in_database = profile_id
                if (name_of_field_in_database != 'profile_id') {
                    var string_from_database = document[name_of_field_in_database];
                    build_map_of_santized_words_to_uuid_ids(name_of_field_in_database, string_from_database, document['item_id']);
                }
            });
        }
        })
    .catch(function(e) {
            console.log('Error:     calling code was get_map_of_santized_words_to_uuid_ids'); 
            console.log('query was: ' + query); 
        console.error(e);      
    });
}
```

Each of these functions has a "catch" clause attached, so I assume if it was the cause of the error, then I would see that in the log.

Comment: Instead of banging against the low-level MySQL driver, using [Sequelize](http://sequelizejs.com) will give you more control over errors. You can `catch` them and backtrack to the root cause.

Comment: Show your initialization code, we can't guess.

Comment: Paul, I am sorry if I was unclear, but whatever code is throwing the error is code that I don't know about. The initialization code that I wrote runs correctly, and without error, and loads the data that I expect to see loaded. But in the logs, there are 5 errors that appear every time I start the app. I am worried about what causes those errors. I am trying to track them down.

Comment: Tadman, we use knex which appears to do the same thing as Sequelize. Every database call has a "catch" clause attached to it. I've posted an example above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Errors in question are not caused by the code that you have included in the question.

To find out what is happening when those errors are sent try to run the app with environment variable `DEBUG=knex:*`. That will show you what is happening in the connection pool and what queries are sent to DB.

```
export DEBUG=knex:*
cd ~/yourapp
node server.js
```

or just

```
cd ~/yourapp
DEBUG=knex:* node server.js
```

Also try to remove code from your application until you have minimal amount of code in application, which still produces those errors. After that it should be pretty easy to find the root cause of the problem.

One more thing that you can do is to add debug info to

```
knex.on('query-error', function (err, obj) { ... });
```

event and check if that catches those errors.

Comment: Hmm, I get this error: DEBUG=knex:*
          ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Comment: @LRK9 that must be set to environment variables of shell. I'll update the answer with an example.

Comment: @LRK9 If you get that error you could try wrapping the value in quotes. eg: `DEBUG="knex:*"`